# coder textarea in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I need a textarea that looks more like an programing environment, like notepad++. Basically, all I want is to insert TABs and keeps the cursor in the same indenting level as the previous line.

Any help on building my own would be greatly apreciated as well (my javascript/jquery skills are very basic).

thanks (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Code Mirror](http://codemirror.net/) would be a great option, it's easy to use with your skills. 
You can also check this Wikipedia post for more information. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors

Good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this link which will help you decide which editor to use based on your requirement. It has provided wide variety of JavaScript based editors with support for various browsers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin for TABs http://teddevito.com/demos/textarea.html